# Regexp match all digit except the ones included in dateTime format

Tags: java, regex, format

I am currently looking for a *regexp* that match (negative) digit excepts the one that are contained in a date time format.

**Exemple:**

```
WHERE id=2 and date > 1990-11-10
=> 2
```

should be matched.
I tried several solutions but none give me the result i except.
Here is what i already tried:

`[-]?\d+[^(\d+-\d+-\d+)]`   => char-class value out-of-range

`(?<=(=|>|<| ))[-]?\d+$` => Not bad but don't match digit that are not at the end of the line

`(?<=(=|>|<| ))[-]?\d+` => don't exclude first digit of dateTime format

`(?<=(=|>|<| ))[-]?\d+(<!(:|-))` => Invalid pattern in look-behind.

The last solution seemed the best but i don't understand the error.
I used this link http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html to build them and rubular to test.

Here is my test sheet: http://rubular.com/r/2bXr53XTpq

BTW: Here is the code we use:

```
 public static String formatCondition(String condition) {
        if (condition != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Pattern pNumbers = Pattern.compile("(?<=(=|>|<| ))[-]?\\d+");

                Matcher mNumbers = pNumbers.matcher(condition);
                condition = mNumbers.replaceAll("'$1'");

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return condition;
    }
```

So I'm looking for the correct regexp or an other solution.
Thanks !

Edit: The error "Invalid pattern in look-behind" appears apparently only in Ruby (as rubular is for Ruby but still better that the other^^). I tested on `http://www.regexe.com/` but still wrong result ('22' and '00' are matched)

Edit2: VKS' answer: `(?<=[^\w-:])[+-]?\d+(?=\s|$)` works, i let if here if someone else need !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=[^\w-:])[+-]?\d+(?=\s|$)
```

You can use this instead.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/24

Comment: Aww yeah fast answer and that work perfectly ! Thank you !